# Converting an Array to list and adding values

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to add a value to an array by converting it to a list

```
Dim oItemSubmit As InventoryService.InventoryItemSubmit

 Dim oAttInfo As New InventoryService.AttributeInfo
 oAttInfo.Name = "FeatName"
 oAttInfo.Value = "value"
 oItemSubmit.AttributeList.ToList().Add(oAttInfo)
```

AttributeList is an array on AttributeInfo. But the code doesn't seem to work. Any ideas

Thanks 
Jothish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AttributeList.ToList()` is making an copy, and you are inserting into copy, not into original array

You can use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx#Y818) to add element or sequence

*C# sample*

```
oItemSubmit.AttributeList = oItemSubmit.AttributeList.Concat(new []{oAttInfo}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oItemSubmit.AttributeList.ToList().Add(oAttInfo)
```

is adding the element to a **temporary list** which is created and then **not used**.

You need to store the reference and then add to it:

```
Dim myList as List<MyType>
myList = oItemSubmit.AttributeList.ToList()
myList.Add(oAttInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks Aliostad. I was thinking of some one liner to do the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `oItemSubmit.AttributeList.ToList()` call creates a whole new instance of `List(Of AttributeInfo)` class, which has nothing to do with the original array other than that it contains items from it. Adding items to it will not add items to said array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
oItemSubmit.AttributeList = theNewList.ToArray
```